# React redux Undo Stack not updating elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using Redux in my React app.  In this module I have a list of objects which when moved update the database and add the entire list to an array of desk locations.  The format I am using is `deskMoves[[],[],[]...]`
Every time I make a change to a desk I add the updated list to the stack.  Next I added a key handler to capture ctrl+z in order to implement an undo function, and also added a `currentMove` integer variable to the store.
Stepping through the code everything seems to work according to plan except that the screen is not updated until I click on the last changed desk (which highlights is) at which point it moves to the previous location.  The code is in multiple parts so I will try to sort them out appropriately (this is a very complex standalone app functioning as a module in a larger SPA site)

```
//Layout.js
//I am going to include the entire page in case I have missed something obscure in the code
//The relevant functions should be handleKeyPress(), buildDesks() and render()


import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
// import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import Draggable from '../Elements/Draggable';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Loading } from '../Elements/LoadingComponent';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {
    Layout_Get_Sites,
    Layout_Get_Map_Background,
    Layout_Set_Current_Site,
    Layout_Get_Desk_Types,
    Layout_Fetch_Desks,
    Layout_Undo_Change,
    Layout_Redo_Change,
    Layout_Clear_Desk,
    Layout_Delete_Desk,
    Layout_Restore_All,
    Layout_Update_Desk_Data,
    Layout_Get_UserImages,
    Layout_Create_Desk,
    Layout_Set_Current_Desk
} from '../../redux/Creators/Layout_Creator';
import '../../shared/styles/layout.css';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        layout: state.layout,
        roles: state.siteMap.siteMapData.userRoles
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    //add action creators here - by reference?
    return {
        Layout_Set_Current_Site: (siteId) => { dispatch(Layout_Set_Current_Site(siteId)) },
        Layout_Get_Sites: () => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Sites()) },
        Layout_Get_Map_Background: (siteId) => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Map_Background(siteId)) },
        Layout_Get_Desk_Types: () => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Desk_Types()) },
        Layout_Fetch_Desks: (siteId) => { dispatch(Layout_Fetch_Desks(siteId)) },
        Layout_Undo_Change: (render) => { dispatch(Layout_Undo_Change(render)) },
        Layout_Redo_Change: (render) => { dispatch(Layout_Redo_Change(render)) },
        Layout_Clear_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Clear_Desk(deskId)) },
        Layout_Delete_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Delete_Desk(deskId)) },
        Layout_Update_Desk_Data: (desk) => { dispatch(Layout_Update_Desk_Data(desk)) },
        Layout_Get_UserImages: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Get_UserImages(deskId)) },
        Layout_Create_Desk: (type, siteId, height, width) => { dispatch(Layout_Create_Desk(type, siteId, height, width)) },
        Layout_Restore_All: () => { dispatch(Layout_Restore_All()) },
        Layout_Set_Current_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Set_Current_Desk(deskId)) }
    };
}

class LayoutMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            width: 0,
            edit: false,
            details: '',
            deskStatus: { top: 0, left: 0 }
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //begin initial load after component is built
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
        this.props.Layout_Restore_All();
        this.props.Layout_Get_Sites();
        this.props.Layout_Get_Desk_Types();
        this.handleResize();
        document.addEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress)
    }

    /************************************************ */
    //                  Utility Functions             //
    /************************************************ */

    changeMap = (target) => {
        this.clickDesk(null, null);
        const site = parseInt(target.value);
        this.props.Layout_Set_Current_Site(site);
        const siteId = this.props.layout.maps[site].id;
        this.props.Layout_Get_Map_Background(siteId);
        this.props.Layout_Fetch_Desks(siteId);
    }

    getScale = () => {
        const currentMap = this.props.layout.currentMap;
        const map = this.props.layout.maps[currentMap];
        const scale = parseFloat(map.scale);

        const wd = parseInt(this.state.width / 12 * 10);

        const realWd = map.Width * scale;
        const newScale = wd / realWd;
        return newScale;
    }

    getDesks = () => {
        const desks = [...this.props.layout.deskMoves[this.props.layout.currentMove]];
        return desks;
    }

    updateStats = () => {
        alert("Update");
    }

    clearUserStats = () => {
        alert("Clear Stats");
    }

    checkChanged = (e) => {
        let check = e.target;
        this.setState({ edit: check.checked })
    }


    updateProperties = (data) => {
        let string = `Top: ${data.top}, Left:${data.left}`;
        // data = this.state.details + ', ' + data
        this.setState({ details: string });
    }

    /************************************************ */
    //                  Event Handlers                //
    /************************************************ */

    handleResize = () => {
        this.setState({
            width: window.innerWidth,
            deskStatus: null
        });
    }

    handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if (this.state.edit) {
            switch (e.code) {
                case 'KeyZ':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) {
                        this.props.Layout_Undo_Change(this.forceUpdate);
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'KeyY':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) {
                        this.props.Layout_Redo_Change(this.forceUpdate);
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    mouseUp = (e, deskId, data) => {
        const desks = this.getDesks();
        let desk = desks[deskId];
        if (data.dragged && this.state.edit) {
            this.clickDesk(e, deskId);
            const scale = this.getScale();
            const newX = parseInt(data.left / scale);
            const newY = parseInt(data.top / scale);
            desk.x = newX + "";
            desk.y = newY + "";
            this.props.Layout_Update_Desk_Data(desk);
        }
        else {
            this.clickDesk(e, deskId);
        }

    }

    clickDesk = (e, deskId) => {
        if (deskId !== null && deskId !== undefined && deskId !== false) {
            const desks = this.getDesks();
            let desk = desks[deskId];
            this.props.Layout_Set_Current_Desk(desk);
        }
        else {
            this.props.Layout_Set_Current_Desk(null);
        }
    }

    rightClick = (e, deskId) => {
        if (this.state.edit) {
            const desks = this.getDesks();
            const desk = desks[deskId];
            let rotation = parseInt(desk.rotation);
            rotation += 90;
            if (rotation >= 360) rotation -= 360;
            desk.rotation = rotation;

            this.props.Layout_Set_Current_Desk(desk);
            this.props.Layout_Update_Desk_Data(desk);
        }
    }


    /************************************************ */
    //                  Drawing Functions             //
    /************************************************ */
    showAdmin = () => {
        const roles = this.props.roles;
        if (roles.toLowerCase().indexOf('admin') >= 0) {
            return (<span style={{ 'whiteSpace': 'nowrap', 'backgroundColor': '#ccc' }}>
                <label htmlFor='layoutEditSelect'>Edit</label>&nbsp;
                <input id='layoutEditSelect' type='checkbox' onClick={(e) => this.checkChanged(e)}
                />
            </span>
            );
        }
        else {
            return <span></span>
        }
    }

    buildMapOptions = () => {
        var ret = this.props.layout.maps.map((site, index) => {
            return (<option value={index} key={index}>{site.SiteName}</option>);
        });
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <option id='0'>Select Site...</option>
                {ret}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    buildDesks = () => {
        const newScale = this.getScale();
        const layout = this.props.layout;
        const desks = this.getDesks();

        let ret = desks.map((desk, index) => {
            let deskImg = null;
            try {
                let dImg = layout.deskTypes.find(
                    d => parseInt(d.deskType) === parseInt(desk.deskType)
                );
                deskImg = dImg.deskImage;
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            }
            const userName = desk.UserLogon !== (null || '') ? desk.UserLogon : "Unassigned";

            const top = Math.trunc(parseInt(parseInt(desk.y) * newScale));
            const left = Math.trunc(parseInt(parseInt(desk.x) * newScale));

            let imgStyle = {
                width: `${parseInt(parseInt(desk.width) * newScale)}px`,
                height: `${parseInt((parseInt(desk.height) * newScale))}px`,
                transform: `rotate(${parseInt(desk.rotation)}deg)`,
                position: 'absolute'
            }
            if (layout.currentDesk && desk.id === layout.currentDesk.id) {
                imgStyle.border = '2px solid cyan';
            }
            const url = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${deskImg}`;
            try {
                return (
                    <Draggable key={desk.id}
                        index={index}
                        enabled={this.state.edit}
                        left={left}
                        top={top}
                        onMove={this.updateProperties}
                        onStop={this.mouseUp}
                        onRightClick={this.rightClick}
                    >
                        <div style={{ position: 'relative' }} className='deskImg'>
                            <img style={imgStyle} alt={userName} src={url} />
                        </div>
                    </Draggable>
                );
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
                return null;
            }
        });//desks.map
        // this.clickDesk(null);
        return ret;
    }//buildDesks

    buildMap = () => {
        let url = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==';
        try {
            let currentMap = this.props.layout.currentMap;
            let map = this.props.layout.maps[currentMap];
            let mapImage = map.SiteBackground;
            //use map image once it is loaded
            if (mapImage !== undefined) {
                url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + mapImage;
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <img id="Layout_SiteMap_Img"
                    style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                    }}
                    src={url}
                    alt=''
                    onClick={(e) => this.clickDesk(e, false)}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    showStatus = () => {
        let desk = this.props.layout.currentDesk;
        if (desk === null) return (<div></div>);

        const visible = desk !== null ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        let left = parseInt(window.innerWidth - 225);
        return (
            <div className='editData'
                style={{ left: left + 'px', visibility: visible }}>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <div id="Layout_UserImg" title="Click to upload new user image" className='Layout_userImg'>
                            <div id="Layout_UserImgLabel">
                                Click to
                                upload new
                                    user image</div>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_Manager'>Manager</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_Manager">
                        {desk.Manager}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_User'>User</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_User">
                        {desk.UserName}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_EmpId'>Emp. Id</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_EmpId">
                        {desk.UserLogon}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_Extension'>Extension</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_Extension">
                        {desk.Extension}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_Department'>Department</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_Department">
                        {desk.Department}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_DBRowId'>DB Id</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_DBRowId">
                        {desk.id}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_DeskID'>Desk ID</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_DeskID">
                        {desk.DeskID}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='statusRow'>
                    <Col sm={5} className='statusDivHeading'><label htmlFor='Layout_Assets'>Assets</label></Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className='statusDivData Layout_Text_Input' contentEditable={true}
                        suppressContentEditableWarning={true} id="Layout_Assets">
                        {desk.Assets}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col offset={1} sm={5} className='Layout_Button_Col '>
                        <button onClick={this.updateStats}>Save</button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={5} style={{ textAlign: 'left' }} className='Layout_Button_Col ' >
                        <button onClick={this.clearUserStats}>Clear</button>
                    </Col>
                </Row >
            </div >
        )
    }

    render = () => {
        if (this.props.layout.isLoading) {
            return (<Loading title="Site Layout" />);
        }
        else if (this.props.layout.isLoadingMap) {
            const map = this.props.layout.maps[this.props.layout.currentMap];
            const siteName = map.SiteName;
            return (
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={1}></Col>
                    <Col sm={10} id="Layout_Map_Container">
                        <Loading title={"map '" + siteName + "'"} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            );
        }
        else if (this.props.layout.mapLoaded) {
            return (
                <div>

                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={1}>
                            {this.showAdmin()}
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={10}>
                            {this.state.details} {this.props.layout.currentMove}
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={1}>
                            <select onChange={(e) => this.changeMap(e.target)}>
                                {this.buildMapOptions()}
                            </select>
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={10} id="Layout_Map_Container">
                            {this.buildMap()}
                            {this.buildDesks()}

                        </Col>
                    </Row >
                    {this.showStatus()}
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={1}>
                        <select onChange={(e) => this.changeMap(e.target)}>
                            {this.buildMapOptions()}
                        </select>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10} id="Layout_Map_Container">
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            );
        }
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LayoutMap);
```

```
//Layout_Creator.js
//only including the functions that get called in this process

export const Layout_Undo_Change = (render) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    let currentMove = state.layout.currentMove;
    // let currentDesks = { ...state.layout.deskMoves[currentMove] };
    if (currentMove > 0)
        currentMove--;
    let newDesks = state.layout.deskMoves[currentMove];

    let init = fetchInit();
    init.method = "POST";
    const deskData = { mode: 'UPDATEMANY', data: newDesks };
    init.body = JSON.stringify(deskData);
    let myReq = new Request(`/dataAPI/Layout/`, init);
    fetch(myReq)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error("Error " + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            var err = new Error(error.message);
            throw err;
        })
        .then((response) => { return response.json() })
        .then((data) => {
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(data); //make sure we have an object not a string
            }
            catch (ex) {

            }
            finally {
                dispatch({
                    type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_MOVES,
                    payload: currentMove
                });
                render();
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_FAILED,
                payload: err.message
            });
        });
}

//not sure if this function should prove relevant
export const Layout_Fetch_Desks = (siteId, current = null) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    //get all data for desk - should come from site
    //fetch numdesks
    var init = fetchInit();
    let req = new Request(`/dataAPI/Layout/GETDESKS?siteId=${siteId}`, init);
    fetch(req)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error("Error " + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            var err = new Error(error.message);
            throw err;
        })
        .then((deskResponse) => { return deskResponse.json() })
        .then((desk) => {
            try {
                const state = getState();
                let moves = [...state.layout.deskMoves];
                if (current === null) {
                    moves.push(desk.desks);
                    // moves.length = current; //if this is an update by keypress delete additional
                    current = moves.length - 1;
                    dispatch({ //set the most current set of desks
                        type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_UPDATE_MOVES,
                        payload: moves
                    })
                }
                return dispatch({ //set which set of desks to use
                    type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_MOVES,
                    payload: current
                })

            }
            catch (ex) {
                return null;
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_FAILED,
                payload: err.message
            })
        });
}
```

```
//Layout_Reducer.js
import * as ActionTypes from '../ActionTypes';

export const layout = (state = {
    isLoading: true,
    isLoadingMap: false,
    mapLoaded: false,
    currentMap: null,
    currentDesk: null,
    maps: [],
    desks: [],
    deskTypes: [],
    deskMoves: [],
    currentMove: 0,
    selectedDesk: null,
    editMode: false,
    errMess: null
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SITES_LOADING:
            return { ...state, isLoading: true };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKS_LOADING:
            return { ...state, isLoadingDesks: true, desks: [] };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_MAP_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state, isLoadingMap: true, desks: [],
                selectedDesk: null, editMode: false
            };

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_MAP_LOADED:
            return { ...state, isLoadingMap: false, mapLoaded: true, maps: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_MAPS_LOADED:
            return { ...state, maps: action.payload, isLoading: false };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKTYPES_LOADED:
            return { ...state, deskTypes: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESK_LOADED:
            return { ...state, desks: action.payload };

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_SELECTED_DESK:
            return { ...state, selectedDesk: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_EDITMODE:
            return { ...state, editMode: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESK_DELETED:
            return { ...state, desks: action.payload, selectedDesk: null }

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_CURRENT_DESK:
            return { ...state, currentDesk: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_ACTIVE_MAP:
            return { ...state, currentMap: action.payload };

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_UPDATE_MOVES:
            return { ...state, deskMoves: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_MOVES:
            return { ...state, currentMove: action.payload };

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_FAILED:
            return {
                ...state, isLoadingMap: false, isLoadingDesks: false,
                errMess: action.payload, pageUsageData: []
            };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_RESTORE_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true, isLoadingMap: false, mapLoaded: false, currentMap: null,
                maps: [], desks: [], deskTypes: [], deskMoves: [], currentMove: 0,
                selectedDesk: null, editMode: false, errMess: null
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in this mess of code there is a reason that things are not updating correctly.  My suspicion lies in the asynchronous nature of React but I am not certain how to circumvent that.

Comment: Have you got redux logger middleware on? its a big help. 
Its likely you're passing an instance of the state into redux - ie. mutating state. This will cause unwanted behaviour. If you're at a loss, my first course of action would be to go through and make all objects you're passing into dispatch clones... dispatch(myAction( {...myData } )) instead of dispatch(myAction(myData)). If it starts working then you know you are mutating state so start taking them away until you find which one is causing it. Then examine whats happening so you can avoid it next time...it can be a painful one.

Comment: Actually in this case it is a fairly simple thing to check.  From Layout.js the only thing I am dispatching is the changed desk which is taken from a clone of the desk list (getDesks() function).  Once I save the desk data then I reload all the desks again which adds those desks to [...deskMoves].  Everything I am dispatching is definitely a clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extracting each component into it's own class, and compiled them with another class into a single component to add to the page.  This "desks" component handled all undo and undo stack functions.