# React redux state change does not cause update even after deep copy of all state data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which when using `CTRL+Z` should trigger an undo action.  Tracing the code through it is obvious that the state is updated correctly and that the arrays in it are not being mutated.  However the component is not rerendered until I click on it, which causes a highlight to occur.  At this point the component jumps to its previous location.  I have attempted using forceUpdate() after the undo action is dispatched but that did not succeed either.

My reducer is a single line returning state and the new object as the action.payload.  My action creator reads the original data, clones everything (some of them multiple times in a 'swing wildly' attempt to solve this) and then dispatches the undo action and data to the reducer.

Stepping through the code and comparing values shows me that everything seems correct so I cannot see where the issue is.

Here is my action creator:

```
export const Layout_Undo_Change = (callback) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    const desks = state.layout_moveData.desks;
    //if no past to undo to
    if (desks.past.length === 0) return;
    const previous = clone(desks.past)[desks.past.length - 1];
    const undoPast = clone(desks.past.slice(0, desks.past.length - 1));
    const undoFuture = clone([desks.present, ...clone(desks.future)])
    const undoDesks = { past: undoPast, future: undoFuture, present: previous };
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_UNDO_MOVES, payload: undoDesks });
    // callback();
}
```

and here is the reducer:

```
export const layout_moveData = (state = {
    desks: {
        past: [],
        present: null,
        future: []
    }
}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKS_LOADING:
            return { ...state, desks: { present: [], past: [], future: [] } };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKS_LOADED:
            return { ...state, desks: { present: action.payload, past: [], future: [] } };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESK_DELETED:
            return { ...state, desks: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_RESTORE_ALL:
            return { ...state, desks: { present: [], past: [], future: [] } };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_MOVES:
            return { ...state, desks: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_UNDO_MOVES:
            return { ...state, desks: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_REDO_MOVES:
            return { ...state, desks: action.payload };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

and finally here is the calling line from the component:

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        console.log("Layout.handleKeyPress");
        if (this.state.edit) {
            switch (e.code) {
                case 'KeyZ':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) {
                        this.props.Layout_Undo_Change(this.forceUpdate);
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                        this.forceUpdate();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'KeyY':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) {
                        //this.props.Layout_Redo_Change();
                        UndoMove.redo();
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

***Edit - adding mapState code***

mapDispatchToProps code:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    //add action creators here - by reference?
    return {
        Layout_Set_Current_Site: (siteId) => { dispatch(Layout_Set_Current_Site(siteId)) },
        Layout_Get_Sites: () => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Sites()) },
        Layout_Get_Map_Background: (siteId, callback) => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Map_Background(siteId, callback)) },
        Layout_Get_Desk_Types: () => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Desk_Types()) },
        Layout_Fetch_Desks: (siteId) => { dispatch(Layout_Fetch_Desks(siteId)) },
        Layout_Undo_Change: (callback) => { dispatch(Layout_Undo_Change(callback)) },
        Layout_Redo_Change: () => { dispatch(Layout_Redo_Change()) },
        Layout_Clear_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Clear_Desk(deskId)) },
        Layout_Delete_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Delete_Desk(deskId)) },
        Layout_Update_Desk_Data: (desk, deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Update_Desk_Data(desk, deskId)) },
        Layout_Get_UserImages: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Get_UserImages(deskId)) },
        Layout_Create_Desk: (type, siteId, height, width) => { dispatch(Layout_Create_Desk(type, siteId, height, width)) },
        Layout_Restore_All: () => { dispatch(Layout_Restore_All()) },
        Layout_Set_Current_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Set_Current_Desk(deskId)) }
    };
}
```

mapStateToProps code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        layout: state.layout,
        layout_moveData: state.layout_moveData,
        roles: state.siteMap.siteMapData.userRoles
    }
}
```

Any help to point me in the correct direction would be awesome.

Comment: Can you show your code that is actually reading the data from the store in the component (ie, `mapState` or `useSelector`)?  Also, note that you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which would simplify all this logic considerably, and that [you should probably be doing all that data manipulation in the reducer itself](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers).

Comment: @markerikson I have added mapDispatch as well as mapState.  I will also look at the toolkit package.

Comment: @HMR I have not yet looked at the devtools, but in stepping through the code I am comparing the changes and know that the variables being passed into state are correct, and also that the state is updated accordingly.  My fear is that somewhere I am manipulating state and am not sure where.

Comment: Definitely start by using the Redux DevTools. Was the action actually dispatched? Did the state update the way you expected it to?  Then, did your `mapState` run?  Is the data returned by `mapState` actually different than the last time it ran?  Also, one other side note: if you're going to use `connect`, you should use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) instead of writing it as a function. It'll be _wayyyy_ shorter :)

Comment: @markerikson I have been using the DevTools.  The store is being maintained and the state is being changed correctly.  Everything is working perfectly except that the position on the page is not being updated.  Even the top and left coordinates passed on the re-render are the correct ones, but it is not being displayed in the correct position.

Comment: @HMR As I posted in the initial question, I have tracked the state all the way through from the CTRL+Z to the re-render of the desk, and the state is correct and modified properly according to the dispatch.  Everything is correct except that the position on the page is not updated according to the new state, which values are being passed and posted in the CSS or the desk component.

Comment: Can't really say anything without seeing some kind of a CodeSandbox or repo that actually demonstrates this issue, so I can take a look myself.

Comment: Sadly this whole thing is behind a corporate firewall and is heavily dependent on the server for data that I am not sure creating a sandbox is feasible.

Comment: Yeah, I know that feeling :)  Unfortunately, there really isn't enough info for me to provide any further feedback here.

Comment: Used the same solution as in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256131/react-redux-undo-stack-not-updating-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256131/react-redux-undo-stack-not-updating-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extrapolated all components and items to separate classes to better handle individual state changes rather than dealing with everything from top down

Comment: Good of you to follow up on this, but this doesn't seem like a very complete answer.

Comment: In order to give a complete answer I would need to post several pages of code to be able to explain beyond what I have said.  The entire solution was to completely refactor all the related code to allow more flexibility in the stack.  My primary focus was to clean up old questions that hadn't been answered and a solution had been found.  Being more than a year old the specificity of the answer is difficult if not impossible to accomplish.