# React-Redux changed state is not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have built a fairly large react-redux application.  In one component I have added an undo feature.  Tracing the state all the way through it is definitely being updated and not mutated.  It even re-renders the component and all child components.  However on the page the component position is not modified until I click the component to either move it again or highlight it.

I have definitely verified that this is not a case of mutated state and have stepped through all the redux code to ensure that the shallow equality fails and I have added breakpoints on the main component and the child component which should be moved.

I will add code if you want to see it but my question is why a re-rendered component in React would not re-render in the updated position on the screen, even though the top and left coordinates have definitely changed?

**Edit adding code**

```
//layout.js

const mapLayoutDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    //add action creators here - by reference?
    return {
        Layout_Set_Current_Site: (siteId) => { dispatch(Layout_Set_Current_Site(siteId)) },
        Layout_Get_Sites: () => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Sites()) },
        Layout_Get_Map_Background: (siteId, callback) => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Map_Background(siteId, callback)) },
        Layout_Get_UserImages: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Get_UserImages(deskId)) },
        Layout_Create_Desk: (type, siteId, height, width) => { dispatch(Layout_Create_Desk(type, siteId, height, width)) },
        Layout_Restore_All: () => { dispatch(Layout_Restore_All()) },
        Layout_Undo_Change: (callback) => { dispatch(Layout_Undo_Change(callback)) },
        Layout_Redo_Change: () => { dispatch(Layout_Redo_Change()) },
        Layout_Fetch_Desks: (siteId) => { dispatch(Layout_Fetch_Desks(siteId)) },
        Layout_Get_Desk_Types: () => { dispatch(Layout_Get_Desk_Types()) },
        Layout_Set_Current_Desk: (desk) => { dispatch(Layout_Set_Current_Desk(desk)) }
    };
}

getDesks = () => {
    console.log("Layout.getDesks");
    // const d = this.props.layout_moveData.desks.present;
    const desks = clone(this.props.layout_moveData.present);
    return desks;
}

   handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        console.log("Layout.handleKeyPress");
        if (this.state.edit) {
            switch (e.code) {
                case 'KeyZ':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) {
                        this.props.Layout_Undo_Change();
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                        // this.forceUpdate();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'KeyY':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) {
                        //this.props.Layout_Redo_Change();
                        UndoMove.redo();
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    buildDesks = () => {
        const desks = this.getDesks();
        let ret = desks.map((desk, index) =>
            <Desk
                key={index}
                desks={desks}
                index={index}
                deskTypes={this.props.layout.deskTypes}
                scale={this.getScale()}
                editable={this.state.edit}
            />
        );
        return ret;
    }

    render=()=>{

            return (
                <div>

                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={1}>
                            {this.showAdmin()}
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={10}>
                            {this.state.details}
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={1}>
                            <select onChange={(e) => this.changeMap(e.target)}>
                                {this.buildMapOptions()}
                            </select>
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={10} id="Layout_Map_Container">
                            {this.buildMap()}
                            {this.buildDesks()}
                        </Col>
                    </Row >
                    {this.showStatus()}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

```
//desks.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Draggable from '../../Elements/Draggable';

import {
    Layout_Clear_Desk,
    Layout_Delete_Desk,
    Layout_Update_Desk_Data,
    Layout_Set_Current_Desk
} from '../../../redux/Creators/Layout_Creator';

import '../../../shared/styles/layout.css';
const clone = require('rfdc')();

const mapDesksStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        layout: state.layout,
        layout_moveData: state.layout_moveData
    }
}

const mapDesksDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        Layout_Clear_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Clear_Desk(deskId)) },
        Layout_Delete_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Delete_Desk(deskId)) },
        Layout_Update_Desk_Data: (desk, deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Update_Desk_Data(desk, deskId)) },
        Layout_Set_Current_Desk: (deskId) => { dispatch(Layout_Set_Current_Desk(deskId)) }

    }
}

class Desk extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            desk: clone(props.desks[props.index]),
            desks: clone(props.desks)
        }
    }

    rightClick = (e, deskId) => {
        if (this.props.editable) {
            const desk = this.state.desk;
            let rotation = parseInt(desk.rotation);
            rotation += 90;
            if (rotation >= 360) rotation -= 360;
            desk.rotation = rotation;

            this.props.Layout_Set_Current_Desk(desk);
            this.props.Layout_Update_Desk_Data(desk);
        }
    }

    updateProperties = (data) => {
        let string = `Top: ${data.top}, Left:${data.left}`;
        // data = this.state.details + ', ' + data
        this.setState({ details: string });
    }

    mouseUp = (e, deskId, data) => {
        console.log("Layout.mouseUp");
        const desks = clone(this.state.desks);
        // let desk = ;
        if (data.dragged && this.props.editable) {
            // this.clickDesk(e, deskId);
            const scale = this.props.scale;
            const newX = parseInt(data.left / scale);
            const newY = parseInt(data.top / scale);

            desks[deskId].x = newX + ""; //convert to strings
            desks[deskId].y = newY + "";

            console.log(this.state.desks);
            console.log(desks);
            this.props.Layout_Update_Desk_Data(desks, deskId);
        }
        else {
            this.clickDesk(e, deskId);
        }

    }

    clickDesk = (e, deskId) => {
        if (deskId !== null && deskId !== undefined && deskId !== false) {

            this.props.Layout_Set_Current_Desk(this.state.desk);
        }
        else {
            this.props.Layout_Set_Current_Desk(null);
        }
    }


    render() {

        let deskImg = null;
        // const desk = this.props.desks[this.props.index];
        let desk = clone(this.state.desk);
        try {
            let dImg = this.props.deskTypes.find(
                d => parseInt(d.deskType) === parseInt(desk.deskType)
            );
            deskImg = dImg.deskImage;
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
        const userName = desk.UserLogon !== (null || '') ? desk.UserLogon : "Unassigned";

        const top = Math.trunc(parseInt(parseInt(desk.y) * this.props.scale));
        const left = Math.trunc(parseInt(parseInt(desk.x) * this.props.scale));

        let imgStyle = {
            width: `${parseInt(parseInt(desk.width) * this.props.scale)}px`,
            height: `${parseInt((parseInt(desk.height) * this.props.scale))}px`,

            position: 'absolute'
        }
        if (this.props.layout.currentDesk && desk.id === this.props.layout.currentDesk.id) {
            imgStyle.border = '2px solid cyan';
        }
        const url = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${deskImg}`;
        try {
            //
            return (
                <Draggable key={desk.id}
                    index={this.props.index}
                    enabled={this.props.editable}
                    left={left}
                    top={top}
                    onMove={this.updateProperties}
                    onStop={this.mouseUp}
                    onRightClick={this.rightClick}
                >
                    <div style={{
                        position: 'relative',
                        transform: `rotate(${parseInt(desk.rotation)}deg)`
                    }}
                        className='deskImg'>
                        <img style={imgStyle} alt={userName} src={url} />
                    </div>
                </Draggable>
            );
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
            return null;
        }

    }//buildDesks
}

export default connect(mapDesksStateToProps, mapDesksDispatchToProps)(Desk);
```

```
//layout_creators.js 
export const Layout_Undo_Change = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    const desks = clone(state.layout_moveData);
    console.log("1", state.layout_moveData.present)
    //if no past to undo to
    if (desks.past.length === 0) return;
    const previous = clone(desks.past[desks.past.length - 1]);
    desks.past.shift();
    const undoPast = clone(desks.past);
    // const undoPast = clone(desks.past).slice(0, desks.past.length - 1);
    const undoFuture = [clone(desks.present), ...clone(desks.future)]
    const undoDesks = { past: undoPast, present: previous, future: undoFuture };
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_UNDO_MOVES, payload: clone(undoDesks) });
    console.log("2", state.layout_moveData.present)
    let init = fetchInit();
    init.method = "POST";
    const deskData = { mode: 'UPDATEMANY', data: previous };
    init.body = JSON.stringify(deskData);
    let myReq = new Request(`/dataAPI/Layout/`, init);
    fetch(myReq)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error("Error " + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            var err = new Error(error.message);
            throw err;
        })

        .catch(err => {
            return dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_FAILED,
                payload: err.message
            });
        });
}
```

```
//layout_reducer.js
import * as ActionTypes from '../ActionTypes';

export const layout = (state = {
    isLoading: true,
    isLoadingMap: false,
    isLoadingDesks: false,
    desksLoaded: false,
    mapLoaded: false,
    currentMap: null,
    currentDesk: null,
    maps: [],
    deskTypes: [],
    editMode: false,
    errMess: null
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SITES_LOADING:
            return { ...state, isLoading: true };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKS_LOADING:
            return { ...state, isLoadingDesks: true, desksLoaded: false };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_MAP_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state, isLoadingMap: true, desks: [],
                currentDesk: null, editMode: false, desksLoaded: false
            };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_MAP_LOADED:
            return { ...state, isLoadingMap: false, mapLoaded: true, maps: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_MAPS_LOADED:
            return { ...state, maps: action.payload, isLoading: false };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKTYPES_LOADED:
            return { ...state, deskTypes: action.payload };

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_CURRENT_DESK:
            return { ...state, currentDesk: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_EDITMODE:
            return { ...state, editMode: action.payload };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESK_DELETED:
            return { ...state, currentDesk: null }
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKS_LOADED:
            return { ...state, currentDesk: null, isLoadingDesks: false, desksLoaded: true }

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_ACTIVE_MAP:
            return { ...state, currentMap: action.payload, desksLoaded: false };

        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_FAILED:
            return {
                ...state, isLoadingMap: false, isLoadingDesks: false, desksLoaded: false,
                errMess: action.payload, pageUsageData: []
            };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_RESTORE_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true, isLoadingMap: false, mapLoaded: false, currentMap: null,
                maps: [], desks: [], deskTypes: [], editMode: false,
                errMess: null, desksLoaded: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const layout_moveData = (state = {

    past: [],
    present: null,
    future: []

}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKS_LOADING:
            return { ...state, present: [], past: [], future: [] };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESKS_LOADED:
            return { ...state, present: action.payload, past: [], future: [] };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_DESK_DELETED:
            return { ...state, present: action.payload.present, past: action.payload.past, future: action.payload.future };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_RESTORE_ALL:
            return { ...state, present: [], past: [], future: [] };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_MOVES:
            return { ...state, present: action.payload.present, past: action.payload.past, future: action.payload.future };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_UNDO_MOVES:
            return { ...state, present: action.payload.present, past: action.payload.past, future: action.payload.future };
        case ActionTypes.LAYOUT_REDO_MOVES:
            return { ...state, present: action.payload.present, past: action.payload.past, future: action.payload.future };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: show the component code

Comment: Are you sure the component is not re rendered (console.log in render should show)? Did you make sure the right action is dispatched and it changes the state in the correct way (redux devtools)? If you are using connect or useSelector can you put a console.log there to make sure the selector is executed and compare result with previous one to make sure it has changed?

Comment: The problem is that the component is being re-rendered but that render is not appearing on the screen until I manipulate the component.  I have traced the code all the way through from the initial connect map props call through to the render.  Everything is working as it should except that the change is not appearing on the page.  I will dump a bunch of code on the page if that helps but I don't believe it will as everything works correctly except the updated display.

Comment: @Geoff - post the component code. When you say, "it doesn't change position" what does that mean? What does it mean that it doesn't update the display "until you manipulate the component"? Manipulate how? There's so many questions, but we need to see some sort of code, as well.

Comment: @Geoff which component isn't updating until it's been "manipulated"? (and what does that mean?). EDIT: Strong suspicion that `key={index}` could be a culprit here.

Comment: @Adam It is the desk component that doesn't get updated until it is clicked on.  In the Desk.JS ```render()``` function the new top and left coordinates are calculated.  Those are the ones which are not being displayed until the desk image is either clicked or dragged on the screen.  Then when I do click it it instantly jumps to the position is should be at and drags from there.
 Why would the key be an issue?  Is there something else I should use as the key, like the desk id that is used in the database?

Comment: @Geoff yes, use the deskID

Comment: Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: @Adam It makes no difference in the functionality.  An interesting thing I noticed was that the jump in position occurs on the mousedown event, event though I am not capturing or acting on that in any way.

Comment: @Geoff don't have the desk or desks be part of the Desk component's `state` - it should be read from the components `props`. (you actually have this line commented out in your desk render function). You're really misusing react in a lot of ways, I'd go back to a [tutorial](https://scotch.io/courses/5-essential-react-concepts-to-know-before-learning-redux/what-is-props-and-state-in-react)  - state is owned by a component, props are owned by another (ancestor) component. The Desk component shouldn't own (hold in it's state) the desk.

Comment: @Adam Yeah - I've done a ton of hacking around trying everything I could possibly think of to get this working.  Hence moving desk and desks to local state rather than using them as props and a bunch of other attempts to see if something (anything) would work.  I reverted it now to pulling desk and desks from props.  With no change, I might add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extrapolated all items in the page to separate components as in [React redux state change does not cause update even after deep copy of all state data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531123/react-redux-state-change-does-not-cause-update-even-after-deep-copy-of-all-state).  This allowed for better stack handling.